# How can I code a residuals plot for CCF data in Python with a 'dumbbell' shape?

Tags: python, plot

I am attempting to create 3 individual plots

1. A plot of HARPS-N CCF data. This data is freely available on the DACE website.  I have been able to create this plot and it produces a signature "V" shape.
2. A plot of the Mean of the CCF data, same shape.
3. A residuals plot. This is where I am having the difficulty, I have coded as much can.  The shape  of the plot should be "dumbbell" in shape. At the moment I am getting an empty plot.

```
This is my code atm.

#import libs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
import numpy as np

# Initial plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# data from the FITS
data_dir = glob.glob('/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/Desktop/harpn_sun_release_package_ccf_2018/2018-01-18/*.fits')

# empty lists for storage
lams = []
fluxs = []

# read the the FITS
for file_path in data_dir:
    hdul = fits.open(file_path)
    data = hdul[1].data
    h1 = hdul[1].header
    flux = data[1]
    w = WCS(h1, naxis=1, relax=False, fix=False)
    lam = w.wcs_pix2world(np.arange(len(flux)), 0)[0]
    lams.append(lam)
    fluxs.append(flux)
    ax.plot(lam, flux)

# Calc mean flux
mean_ccf = np.mean(fluxs, axis=0)

# New fig for main plot
fig_mean, ax_mean = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# plot the mean data
ax_mean.plot(lams[1], mean_ccf, color='k', linewidth=1)

# Mean
ax_mean.set_xlabel('RV [km/s]')
ax_mean.set_ylabel('Normalized CCF')
ax_mean.set_title('Mean CCF')

# Residuals
residuals = fluxs - mean_ccf
fig_res, ax_res = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax_res.plot(lams[1], residuals, color='k', linewidth=1)

# Plot residuals
ax_res.set_xlabel('RV [km/s]')
ax_res.set_ylabel('CCF Residuals')
ax_res.set_title('CCF Residuals')

plt.show()
```